# Attempting to apply classes to elements filtered through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a page for my site where elements can be displayed as a list under a search function.

The layout for my page uses the classes 'small' and 'large' to make elements appear side by side. I am trying to make these elements alternate, so the pattern is as below:

1 - Small 2 - Large

3 - Large 4 - Small

5 - Small 6 - Large

And so on for the full list.

I attempted to solve this through nth-child but as I'm filtering the list through jQuery I cannot then apply the small and large classes to only the active ('.current') classes that are displayed, so I end up with a lot of white space where divs have been filtered out. Therefore I'm trying to apply this to only the 'current' divs within the list.

I've created an inelegant pseudo-solution, but I can't repeat this ad infinitum because numbers like 7,  11 and 19 don't work with the equations.

I've replicated the relevant code below to show what I mean, as you can see the divs at the bottom stop following the pattern.

:even and :odd don't work for this either since 'large' needs to be applied to 2,3,6,7,10,11 and so on.

Not sure if I'm just missing something really obvious here!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if ($('.event-single').hasClass('current')) {
    $('.event-single.current').each(function(index) {
      if ((index + 1) % 3 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('large').removeClass('small');
      }
    })
    $('.event-single.current').filter(function(index) {
      if ((index + 1) % 2 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('large').removeClass('small');
      }
    })
    $('.event-single.current').filter(function(index) {
      if ((index + 1) % 7 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('large').removeClass('small');
      }
    })
    $('.event-single.current').filter(function(index) {
      if ((index + 1) % 11 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('large').removeClass('small');
      }
    })
    $('.event-single.current').filter(function(index) {
      if ((index + 1) % 18 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('large').removeClass('small');
      }
    })
    $('.event-single.current').filter(function(index) {
      if ((index + 1) % 4 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('small').removeClass('large');
      }
    })
    $('.event-single.current').filter(function(index) {
      if ((index + 1) % 9 == 0) {
        $(this).addClass('small').removeClass('large');
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```css
.event-info {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
}

.large {
  width: 60%;
  height: 350px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px
}

.small {
  width: 37%;
  height: 350px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px
}

.list-of-events-inner {
  overflow: hidden
}

.event-single:not(.current) {
  display: none;
}

.event-single .hero-post-mini-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="list-of-events-inner" id="list-of-hotels-inner">

    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do. You should just be able to adjust your javascript - look at the index mod 4, and then you want 0 and 3 to be small if I understand correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.event-single.current').each(function(num, elem) {
    var mod = num % 4;
    if (mod === 0 || mod === 3) {
      $(elem).addClass('small').removeClass('large');
    } else {
      $(elem).addClass('large').removeClass('small');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.event-info {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300px;
}

.large {
  width: 60%;
  height: 350px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px
}

.small {
  width: 37%;
  height: 350px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50px
}

.list-of-events-inner {
  overflow: hidden
}

.event-single:not(.current) {
  display: none;
}

.event-single .hero-post-mini-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">

  <div class="list-of-events-inner" id="list-of-hotels-inner">

    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="event-single current small">
      <div class="event-info">
      </div>
```

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was after. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you have a pattern of small-large-large-small that repeats every 4 items. A fairly simple solution would be to loop over all matching divs and style them according to their index in their group of 4, using their index modulo 4.

e.g.

```
var events = $('.current');
for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
{
  if(i % 4 == 0 || i % 4 == 3)
    events[i].addClass('small').removeClass('large')
  else
    events[i].addClass('large').removeClass('small')
}
```